# Sorting database information by first name not working using @Query annotation, how do i resolve this?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jpql

This is my Student repository..

```java
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Student order by last_name ASC", nativeQuery = true)
  public List<Student> orderByLastName();

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Student order by first_name ASC", nativeQuery = true)
  public List<Student> orderByFirstName();
```

this is my service and my controller

```java
  public List<Student> showAllStudentsByFirst()
  {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Student student : studentRepository.findAll())
    {
      students.add(student);
    }
    studentRepository.orderByFirstName();
    return students;
  }

  public List<Student> showAllStudentsByLast()
  {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Student student : studentRepository.findAll())
    {
      students.add(student);
    }
    studentRepository.orderByLastName();
    return students;
  }
```

```java
  @GetMapping("/listByFirst")
  public String listStudentsByFirst(Model model)
  {
    List<Student> students = studentService.showAllStudentsByFirst();
    model.addAttribute("students", students);

    return "list-students";
  }

  @GetMapping("/listByLast")
  public String listStudentsByLast(Model model)
  {
    List<Student> students = studentService.showAllStudentsByLast();
    model.addAttribute("students", students);

    return "list-students";
  }
```

the url works, and also when I click the button Orderby First, or order by last this is the message displayed in the console

```java
: select student0_.student_id as student_1_1_, student0_.email as email2_1_, student0_.first_name as first_na3_1_, student0_.last_name as last_nam4_1_ from user_db.student student0_
2019-04-15 14:11:46.059 DEBUG 10392 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : SELECT * FROM Student order by first_name ASC
```

All else is working but the name is not returning an acending table by first or last, just for refrence this is my jsp code

```html
   <input type="button" value="Sort By First Name"
               onclick="window.location.href='listByFirst'; return false;"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Sort By Last Name"
               onclick="window.location.href='listByLast'; return false;"/>
```

simply the ordered table is not returning, how do I fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the return of the two order methods. They return a new list that is sorted as defined in the query.

Instead, you execute a `findAll` which creates the output you show. And the call to the order methods simply decays to a noop.

Dump the first four lines of the two methods in the service and simply return the value from the order methods:

```
public List<Student> showAllStudentsByFirst() {
    return studentRepository.orderByFirstName();
}

public List<Student> showAllStudentsByLast() {
    return studentRepository.orderByLastName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

these two methods should be like this

```java
public List<Student> showAllStudentsByFirst() {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Student student : studentRepository.findAll()) {
            students.add(student);
        }
        students = studentRepository.orderByFirstName();
        return students;
    }

    public List<Student> showAllStudentsByLast() {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Student student : studentRepository.findAll()) {
            students.add(student);
        }
        students = studentRepository.orderByLastName();
        return students;
    }
```

you are assigning the database value into the object `students`
so that object needs to be assigned to the method holding the query.